# Re-opening: Rolling a biased dice, Multinomial probability

Tags: probability, statistics

[This is from a 5 and a half year old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704602/rolling-a-biased-dice-multinomial-probability). The problem is:

There's a biased $6$-face dice such that if $X$ denotes the outcome, then
\begin{align*}
P(X = 1) = P(X = 3) &= 0.1,\\
P(X = 2) = P(X = 4) = P(X = 6) &= 0.25, \\
P(X = 5) &= 0.05
\end{align*}

Find $P(\text{two } 4 \text{s and three } 1 \text{s})$ when you roll $6$ of those unfair dice.

**Why do we multiply with $\frac{6!}{2!3!1!} = 60$?**

The number of trials is $6$. The number of occurrences of the permutations of :

1. $(4,4,1,1,1,1)$ is $\frac{6!}{2!4!} = 15$,
2. $(4,4,4,1,1,1)$ is $20$ and that of
3. $(4,4,1,1,1,x)$ is $60$ for each $x \notin \{1,4\}$

How do we account for $(1)$ and $(2)$, and the four occurrences of $(3)$ with just $\frac{6!}{2!3!1!}$?

Edit: I just realized after [@Rezha](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/751970/rezha-adrian-tanuharja) that the question asks for **exactly** two fours and three ones. Then my question is, why's the coefficient $60$ and not $4*60$ (to account for $2,3,5,6$)?

Comment: The original question states “exactly two 4s and three 1s”. (1) and (2) do not satisfy this

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I misread that, thanks for pointing it out. So in that case, why is it $60$ and not $4 * 60$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original question, the person working the problem has decided that
"rolling $2,3,5,$ or $6$ on the first die" should be a single event whose
probability is $0.65.$ They similarly grouped those four outcomes together as a single event for each of the other dice.

If you like, imagine that we took a Sharpie pen and made a big X on every face except the $1$ and the $4$ on every die, and we record each die's value only as $1,$ $4,$ or X.

If you insist on counting $(1,3,4,4,1,1)$, for example, as a separate event from $(1,2,4,4,1,1),$
yes, you will have to write four different formulas of the form

$$ (P(4))^2  (P(1))^3  P(x), $$

once with $P(x) = 0.05,$ once with $P(x) = 0.1,$ and twice with $P(x) = 0.25.$
You will have to multiply by $60$ each time to account for the permutations of the dice.
When you add up your four products with the terms
$0.05,$ $0.1,$ $0.25,$ and $0.25,$ the distributive law of multiplication over addition will ensure that you get a result equal to a single product with the term
$0.05+0.1+0.25+0.25 = 0.65.$
The only difference is you will have done four times as much writing.

I cannot see any possible method in which multiplying by
$4 \cdot 60$ is correct, except the highly artificial technique in which
you assign the "average" probability $0.65/4 = 0.1625$ to each of the faces $2,3,5,6$ on each die.

Multiplying any of the *actual* probabilities of any of those faces by $4$ is a nonsensical step, because the faces do not all have the same probability!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Now if the question asked us to find the same probability without the restriction that the last number has to be one of $\{2,3,5,6\}$, what would have been the answer - $$P(4)^2 P(1)^3 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{6} P(i) M(i) \right)$$ where $M(i)$ denotes the multinomial coefficient? Is there a slick way to do this?